# Making a progress bar with the CSS attr function

Tags: html, css, attr

I'm trying to make a progress bar with the CSS `attr` function, here is my code :

```css
.progress_bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10cm;
  background-color: #cae3ff;
}

.progress {
  height: inherit;
  width: attr(progress);
  background-color: #0077ff;
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress_bar">
  <div class="progress" progress="80%"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see by running the code snippet, the bar doesn't work, I read the docs about the `attr` function and still I don't find the problem, could you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr()` was originally intended for use with the `content` property and support for it there is good.

CSS Values and Units Module Level 4 adds support for *any* property (such as `width`), but that specification is currently a Working Draft and browser support is [non-existent](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20attr).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `width` rule in the `style` attribute like `style="width:50%"`

Answer (score 0):

I found another way :

```css
.progress_bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10cm;
  background-color: #cae3ff;
}

.progress {
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #0077ff;
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress_bar">
  <div class="progress" style="width:80%"></div>
</div>
```

Using the style attribute, instead of creating a new attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```css
.progress_bar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10cm;
  background-color: #cae3ff;
}

.progress {
  height: inherit;
  width: calc(var(--width, 0) * 1%);
  background-color: #0077ff;
  transition: 1s cubic-bezier(1,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress_bar">
  <div class="progress" style="--width: 80;"></div>
</div>
```